# Celery, kombu and django - import error

Tags: python, django, celery, kombu

I am running an application with django, and I wanted to use celery to make some scheduled tasks.

According to the [oficial docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/django.html#broker-django), in my settings.py file I set the broker transport

```
BROKER_URL = 'django://'
```

and added kombu.transport.django to installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'kombu.transport.django',
    ....)
```

However, when I try to sync the database, with `python manage.py syncdb`, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this? I have django installed correctly and the application runs fine if I remove `kombu.transport.django` from installed apps.

**Edit**: this seems to be a problem with kombu. I installed it with `pip install kombu`. When I try to import in a file 'kombu.transport' I get no errors, but when I try to import 'kombu.transport.django' I get an erro:

```
ImportError: No module named django
```

Comment: have you installed kombu? `pip install kombu`

Comment: Yes, it is installed

Answer (score 13):

While it might have happened after your post, the django module was definitely removed from the kombu package.  Current documentation for celery states that as of version 3.1, celery works with Django 'out of the box'.  That means you don't have to modify settings.py to integrate celery (so don't include references to kombu).

Removing references to kombu in settings.py is the correct solution.

This is the commit: https://github.com/celery/kombu/commit/65f982ccf31b86157c39a8feb42081410b83abe2

Answer (score 1):

latest celery has removed support for django as broker. They prefer redis,rabbitmq as their preferred broker.