# Python manage.py ImportError: No module named django

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to get my manage.py script to recognize the django module. pip install req/dev.txt installs all of the modules I would expect it to into my my python virtual environment (stored at .venv).

I think I've narrowed it down to a problem with either my $PYTHON_PATH or with my pip requirements files. I've looped through sys.path, and I see that one of the values points to a folder in .venv that I can confirm contains the django module.

I'm unfortunately at a loss. I've searched through a dozen related questions on Stack Overflow and have yet to find a solution that works. Does anyone have any clues to point me in the right direction?

Error message:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nathan/www/myapp/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nathan/www/myapp/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/nathan/www/myapp/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/nathan/www/myapp/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/nathan/www/myapp/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django
```

Contents of reqs/dev.txt

```
-r common.txt
django-debug-toolbar==1.3.2
```

Contents of reqs/common.txt

```
django==1.8
Fabric==1.10.2
ShopifyAPI>=2.1.5
Sphinx==1.3.1
celery>=3.1.20
django-compressor>=1.5
django-toolbelt>=0.0.1
jdcal>=1.0
kombu>=3.0.35
openpyxl==2.2.5
python-dateutil>=2.4.2
psycopg2>=2.5
requests==2.7.0
whitenoise==2.0
shippo==1.4.0
```

Contents of manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings.dev")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: You should create a virtualenv anyway for your development, doing so (and using it) should solve your issues

Comment: Thank you - while I did have a venv running, I realized that I should verify it was being used (it was), which led me to realize I should dive into the stack trace and just start printing things to debug on which input things are breaking. That led me to my solution, written below! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved after a good night's rest.

The issue was that my INSTALLED_APPS had a reference to `kombu.transport.django`, which seems to be a completely unnecessary dependency we added for celery. More information on that here: [Celery, kombu and django - import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679687/celery-kombu-and-django-import-error)

How I discovered the solution, in case the debugging technique helps anyone else:

I started by diving into the stack trace. I (temporarily) modified the files in `.venv/` to add print statements for the input variables until I found my first clue in `populate()` in `.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py`

Printing through each entry in `populate()` allowed me to see that the package that was breaking was `kombu.transport.django` and NOT the `django` module proper. Deleting that entry from my INSTALLED_APPS solved the problem.

To cleanup I reverted the files in `.venv/` by removing my print statements and I was off and running!