# django with celery raise No module named 'kombu' when runserver

Tags: django, celery, kombu

I made a website with django and I use celery for asynchronous task, when I run:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/car_rental/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/car_rental/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 509, in __getattr__
    module = __import__(self._object_origins[name], None, None, [name])
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celery import _state
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/_state.py", line 17, in <module>
    from celery.utils.threads import LocalStack
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from kombu.utils.objects import cached_property
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kombu'
```

I tried to install kombu:

```
pip install kombu
Collecting kombu
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/7e/44445f7d9031e82b4a1160141de35ca810f44041bf5065b45c68ab0ec9e8/kombu-4.6.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: amqp<2.6,>=2.5.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from kombu)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.18; python_version < "3.8" in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from kombu)
Requirement already satisfied: vine<5.0.0a1,>=1.1.3 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from amqp<2.6,>=2.5.2->kombu)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.18; python_version < "3.8"->kombu)
Installing collected packages: kombu
Successfully installed kombu-4.6.8
```

And now I get this error if a run the server:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 118, in create
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: module 'kombu.transport' has no attribute 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/rouizi/OC_project13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 136, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kombu.transport.django'
```

I know that [the django module was definitely removed from the kombu package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679687/celery-kombu-and-django-import-error) but if I remove kombu I get the first error, how can I fix this ?

I am using `django==3.0.3`, `celery==4.4.1`, `kombu==4.6.8`

Comment: Try pip3 install kombu. There might be an issue with the venv

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 3):

You use
celery 4.4.1 has requirement kombu<4.7,>=4.6.10, but you'll have kombu 4.6.8 which is incompatible.

Please use:

`pip install celery==4.4.6`

`pip install kombu==4.6.10`

and if you want to redis you should this version

`pip install redis==3.2.1`

Then you to terminal and type `python`

[image]

Comment: This does solve the issue of not being able to run django server on a Mac (for me). Thank you